# Sum three different numbers in same cell

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, concatenation, worksheet-function

Could you help me with this: I need formula, which will get this result:

```
3/7+3
4/6+2
5/1+5

12/14+10
```

I know this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(A1:A3,FIND("/",A1:A3)-1))&"/"&SUMPRODUCT(--REPLACE(A1:A3,1,FIND("/",A1:A3),0)
```

I don't know how to add another parameter with "+".

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(A1:A3,FIND("/",A1:A3)-1))&"/"&SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1:A3,FIND("/",A1:A3)+1,FIND("+",A1:A3)-FIND("/",A1:A3)-1))&"+"&SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1:A3,FIND("+",A1:A3)+1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended with a big formula.

`=CONCATENATE(SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(A1:A3,SEARCH("/",A1:A3,1)-1)),"/",SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1:A3,SEARCH("/",A1:A3,1)+1,SEARCH("+",A1:A3,SEARCH("/",A1:A3,1)+1)-SEARCH("/",A1:A3,1)-1)),"+",SUMPRODUCT(--RIGHT(A1:A3,LEN(A1:A3)-SEARCH("+",A1:A3,SEARCH("/",A1:A3,1)+1))))`

Comment: Actually tried by using MID as you, but didn't get it for more than 1 digit in after `/`.